# Kendo Grid Delete (Destroy) is not working (PHP)

Tags: kendo-grid

So I've looked at all the other questions about this sort of issue, and I can't seem to find the answer.  Sorry for the long code here - but can someone tell me why the "Delete" command button would suddenly stop triggering?  It worked perfectly before.  And as you can see, I don't have any code attached to it - it's native.  Now, it simply does nothing.  I've watched in FireBug and nothing's being fired at all.

JQuery and Kendo are loaded as usual - and the button appears properly.  All the other buttons work fine.

[image: Grid Screenshot]

Just can't seem to see what the issue is... any suggestions?  Here's the code for the grid:

```
function generateGrid() {
            $("#teamGrid").kendoGrid({
                columns: [
                    {   title: "First Name", 
                        field: "users_first_name", 
                        attributes: {
                            style: "text-align: center; font-size: 14px;"
                        },
                        filterable: true,
                        headerAttributes: {
                            style: "font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; width: 100px;"
                        }
                    },
                    {   title: "Last Name", 
                        field: "users_last_name", 
                        attributes: {
                            style: "text-align: center; font-size: 14px;"
                        },
                        filterable: true,
                        headerAttributes: {
                            style: "font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; width: 100px;"
                        }
                    },
                    {   title: "Email", 
                        field: "users_email", 
                        attributes: {
                            style: "text-align: center; font-size: 14px;"
                        },
                        filterable: { extra: false },
                        headerAttributes: {
                            style: "font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; width: 300px;"
                        }
                    },
                    {   title: "User Type", 
                        field: "admin_status",
                        attributes: {
                            style: "text-align: center; font-size: 14px;"
                        },
                        filterable: true,
                        headerAttributes: {
                            style: "font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; width: 80px;"
                        },
                        template: function(dataItem) {
                            if ( dataItem.admin_status == 0 ) {
                                return "Team Member";
                            } else if ( dataItem.admin_status == 1 ) {
                                return "Admin";
                            } else if ( dataItem.admin_status == 2 ) {
                                return "Manager";   
                            } else if ( dataItem.admin_status == 3 ) {
                                return "Acct Owner";    
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    { 
                        command: [
                            {   
                                name: "custom1", text: "Edit",
                                click: function(e) {
                                  $uid = this.dataItem(this.select()).users_id;
                                  $(".title h4").filter(":first").css({
                                     color: "blue",
                                     "text-decoration": "underline",
                                     cursor: "pointer"
                                  });
                                  var offset = $(".grid-box").offset();
                                  var newLeft = offset.left+25;
                                  newLeft = newLeft + "px";
                                  var newTop = offset.top+80;
                                  newTop = newTop + "px";

                                  // Get Profile Info
                                  $.getJSON(
                                    '/data/get_profile_data.php',
                                    { users_id: $uid })
                                    .done( function(data) {
                                        $("#users_first_name").val(data[0].users_first_name);
                                        $("#users_last_name").val(data[0].users_last_name);
                                        $("#users_email").val(data[0].users_email);
                                        $("#admin_status").val(data[0].admin_status);
                                        $("#rc").val($uid);

                                        $('#teamGrid').css("display","none");
                                          $('.grid-box2').css({
                                              display: "block",
                                              position: "absolute",
                                              top: newTop,
                                              left: newLeft,
                                           });
                                    });
                                },
                            },
                            {   
                                name: "destroy", text: "Delete"
                            }
                        ],
                        headerAttributes: {
                            style: "width: 120px;"
                        },
                        attributes: {
                            style: "text-align: center;"
                        },
                        title: "&nbsp;"
                    }
                    ],
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "/data/get_team.php"
                        },
                        update: {
                            url: "/data/update_teammate.php",
                            type: "POST"
                        },
                        destroy: {
                            url: "/data/delete_teammember.php",
                            type: "POST"
                        },
                        create:  {
                            url: "",
                            type: "POST"    
                        }
                    },
                    schema: {
                        data: "data",
                        total: function (result) {
                                 result = result.data || result;
                                 return result.length;
                       },
                       model: {
                            id: "users_id"   
                       }
                    },
                    type: "json" 
                },
                pageable: {
                        refresh: true,
                        pageSize: 15,
                        pageSizes: [
                            15
                        ]
                    },
                sortable: true,
                filterable: true,
                autoSync: true,
                scrollable: false,
                selectable: "row",
                reorderable: false,
                toolbar: [
                            { template: kendo.template($("#template").html()) }
                         ]

            }); // END: teamGrid

        } // END: generateGrid function
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: +1 for the detailed description of the problem.
Anyway I did not was any PHP code here, correct me if I am wrong, but why did u tagged the question PHP

Comment: Heh.. you're right.  This is all being written in PHP, but I only quoted the JS portion.  Habit.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand PHP. But JS part should be similar. Kendo grid has the tendency to swallow errors which is painful for the developers to pin point the cause. However why don't you add a small error handler after the schema just to find what it is. I guess every little thing helps when you get stuck!

```
schema: {
            model: {
                id: "ID",
                fields: {
                    ID: { editable: false },
                    NumberOfLoads: { editable: true, type: "number" },
                    Hours: { editable: true, type: "number" },
                    Kilometres: { editable: false },
                    WaterUsage: { editable: true },
                    Driver: { editable: true },
                    Hole: { editable: true }
                }
            },
            errors: "Errors"
        },

        error: function (e) {
            alert(e);
        }
```